# Accessing object methods in numpy.where?

Tags: python, date, numpy

I have data in a numpy array (read from a .csv file). The relevant extract from np.genfromtxt is:

```
dtype = [("Category", "|S10"),
         ("Status", "|S11"),
         ("Date_start", object),
         ("Date_stop", object)],
names=True,
converters={2:lambda d:datetime.strptime(d, "%d/%m/%y"),
            3:lambda d:datetime.strptime(d, "%d/%m/%y")}
)
```

Everything works with one exception — accessing elements of the datetime objects. The following two lines of code return exactly what I expect:

```
print inp['Date_start'][1].month #returns 7
print np.where(inp['Category'] == '"R5"') #returns an array of matching indices
```

but the following line of code throws an `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'month'`

```
print np.where(inp['Date_start'].month == 7)
```

This means I can't return results based on which month things occurred in, which I need to.

Is there any way to get the behaviour I want from np.where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a vectorized attribute getter:

```
def func(a):
    return a.month

vfunc = np.vectorize(func)
```

and then use:

```
np.where(vfunc(inp['Date_start']) == 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed, your `inp['Date_Start']` is a standard `ndarray` with `dtype='object'` and as such, it doesn't have the attributes of its elements.

Apart from the vectorized attribute getter that @user545424 suggested, you can do something like:

```
test = np.fromiter((i.month == 7 for i in inp['Date_start']), 
                   count=inp.size, dtype=bool)
```

(the `count=inp.size` helps `np.fromiter` to run more efficiently. Check the function's documentation).

From there, you can use `test` to filter the elements you want, or get the indices of the items satisfying the condition with `np.zeros(test)`.

If you have a lot of date handling, though, you may want to consider using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), which took over most of the functionalities of [scikits.timseries](http://pytseries.sourceforge.net/). Support for dates in numpy is still considered experimental as I write this.